# SAM PSO(Perform Security Operation):CDS(Compute digital signature) 6982 error

Tags: digital-signature, smartcard, apdu

I'm trying to compute digital signature RSASSA-PSS with sha256 for my IdentityIdentificationData (ASN1).

Directory file address `0x3D00`

Aplication ID `A000000061123A22738F4421`

Private key folder `0x2F01`

My ASN1 encoded hex data after sha256 encoded:

```
860c30a5f2b254ee92cbd3ec5c4282a940853aaef5f36d50ca20050637aaf4b0
```

I'm sending this command after SAM pin verified

MSE:SET

```
002241B606800191840110
SW1SW2:9000
```

Select File

```
00A40800043D002F0100
SW1SW2:9000
```

PSO: Compute Digital Signature

```
002A9E9A20860c30a5f2b254ee92cbd3ec5c4282a940853aaef5f36d50ca20050637aaf4b000
SW1SW2:6982
```

I'm a bit new on smart cards. How can i solve this problem. What is wrong or missing.

**My SAM don't want to algorithm identifier for RSASSA-PSS.**

Answer (score 1):

6982 means: Security condition not satisfied

You should probably send the VERIFY PIN command **directly before** the PSO: Compute Digital Signature. Signature generation generally has very high requirements with regards to PIN, because the user has give consent for each and every signature. Hence the PIN may be invalidated by each command, especially if that command is an MSE:SET command. Selecting a DF by name may also influence the security environment.

So try the following order:

1. SELECT by Name (AID)
2. MSE:SET (for digital signature)
3. VERIFY PIN
4. PSO:COMPUTE DIGITAL SIGNATURE

---

The signature may also be depending on other security related objects such as an authentication key, for instance one used to setup secure messaging.

Comment: (step by step)i'm selecting rsa private key folder (9000) (reading key to be sure) MSE:SET for digital signature (9000) verifying pin (9000) sending pso:cds  6982 i couldn't find to problem

Comment: Is this possibly a PKCS#15 / ISO 7816-15 compliant card? In that case the access conditions should be documented in the file system. Each and every card is different, so please put the card type into the question.

Comment: 002241b606800191840181 mse:set is solved my problem tnx for ur asnwers

Comment: OK, feel free to answer your own question, glad you've got it working; now share the info! ISO 7816-15 is largely the same as PKCS#15. Note that PKCS standards are from RSA Labs, which is kind of defunct, so an ISO workgroup has taken over.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check the **access condition** of **RSA_Sign key** ? If the access condition is **NEVER** then you wont be able to sign with this key. So in such case, SW 6982 make sense.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit new if am i wrong please tell me. i can send 00B00000F4 after select rsa file and i can get response also with 9000

Comment: Your question is not clear to me here, what i can guess is you want to fetch the access conditions of RSA key when selecting the file ?
I certainly believe you wont be able to fetch the access conditions, but instead RSA_Sign key has to be re-personalized.

Comment: When i ask my supporter told me u don't need to create rsa key for compute signature. u can use directly just select file

Comment: how can i fetch access conditions

Comment: "u don't need to create rsa key for compute signature", because the key is pre-personalize in your chip and do you have a personalization script where you do this ? If not, ask to the person who do it for you. In the script, you have the access conditions.

Comment: Documentation says EF.PrKDF : Private key folder information : 0x2F01 first im going there 00A40000023D0000 then 00A40000022F0100 there is not empty and then(MSE:SET) 002241B606800191840110  (last 10(ID) is not empty also 2,3 is not empty)

Comment: If you got the card with EF 2F01 pre-created, then you need to ask the other party to check the access conditions at the creation of file.

Comment: 002241b606800191840181 mse:set is solved my problem tnx for ur asnwers

Comment: glad to hear that !!

Answer (score 0):

`002241b606800191840181` mse:set is worked on me.